# How to set environment variable permanently in zsh on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, zsh

I am trying to set two environment variables on macOS version 10.15.5, I've opened a terminal and tried:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Added the exports to that, saved and exited vi, closed and reopened terminal, I don't see my new exports.

I've also tried:

```
vi ~/.profile
```

Added the exports to that, saved and exited vi, closed and reopened terminal, I don't see the exports there either.

What haven't I done?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @nohillside, zsh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorted, `vi ~/.zshenv`.

Added the exports, save and exit, restart terminal, my system was using the zsh terminal.

Or without restarting the terminal, just add:

`source ~/.zshenv` or `source ~/.profile`

After editing.

Comment: Unless `.profile` sources `.zshenv` sourcing this will not help :-)

Comment: @nohillside, I've done this many times on my own system it works.

Answer (score 12):

### Starting with macOS Catalina --  by default it takes zsh and hence you need to change in zprofile. Please follow below steps

1. Launch Terminal app
2. Create profile file:

   ```
   touch ~/.zprofile
   ```
3. Open file in editor:

   ```
   open ~/.zprofile
   ```
4. Add any exports definitions you need, one by line.

   For example:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home
   export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/installs/gradle-6.8.3
   export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuser/Documents/installs/gradle-6.8.3/bin
   ```
5. Execute new `.zprofile` by either restarting Terminal or using this:

   ```
   source ~/.zprofile
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Short** answer:

```
 vi ~/.zshenv
```

add your env vars to file:

```
export KEY_NAME_HERE=/foo/bar/foobar
export KEY_NAME_HERE=foobar123
```

Don't forget to `source ~/.zshenv` or open a new shell

**Longer** answer as to which file to use as per zsh man page:

> Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv then $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.
> /etc/zshenv is run for all instances of zsh, it is important that it
> be kept as small as possible
>
> If
> the shell is a login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and
> then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile.  As
>
> Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc
> and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.
>
> Finally, if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and
> $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.

If you are using the RCS or GLOBAL_RCS options with /etc/zshenv, then you should review the zsh man page specifically under "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" since that may cause unexpected modifications.

Comment: There is no need to create a non-existing file first with `touch`, `vi` will create it when you save.